# Spring boot application for some reaseon stoped working inside AWS EC2 instance

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, schedule

I have deployed a spring boot application to the AWS EC2 instance. And it works fine for some time. But after a day application just stopped working. I have used different types of EC2, from t2.micro to t3.medium. And only one thing has changed. In a larger EC2 instance, the application works longer without stopping. Memory usage was not high. But something strange was happening with CPU utilization. The application worked with less than 2% CPU utilization, but suddenly it went to 50%, and after that, it stopped working.

This is the main part of the code.

```
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    public void trackChanges() {
        String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        log.info("Start processing new track changes with id {} at {}", uuid, LocalDateTime.now());
        List<Pair<Asset, Fiat>> pairs = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Asset asset : Asset.values()) {
            for (Fiat fiat : Fiat.values()) {
                pairs.add(new Pair<>(asset, fiat));
            }
        }

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(pairs.size());

        for (Pair<Asset, Fiat> assetFiatPair : pairs) {
            executorService.submit(() -> {
                getProfit(assetFiatPair.getFirst(), assetFiatPair.getSecond());
                latch.countDown();
            });
        }

        try {
            latch.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            log.error("TrackChanges was interrupted!", e);
            // Restore interrupted state...
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        executorService.shutdown();
        log.info("Finish processing new track changes with id {} on {}", uuid, LocalDateTime.now());
    }

    private void getProfit(Asset asset, Fiat fiat) {
        Report report = binanceSearchService.check(asset, fiat);

        if (!report.isEmpty()) {
            CompareReport result = comparator.compare(report);
            if (result.isChanged()) {
                messageNotificator.sendMessage(result.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

Memory usage metric
[image]

CPU utilization metric

[image]

'dmesg' command output

```
[    0.761452] rcu: Hierarchical SRCU implementation.
[    0.765381] NMI watchdog: Perf NMI watchdog permanently disabled
[    0.765481] smp: Bringing up secondary CPUs ...
[    0.769067] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
[    0.769410] .... node  #0, CPUs:      #1
[    0.712169] kvm-clock: cpu 1, msr 2fa01041, secondary cpu clock
[    0.771735] kvm-guest: stealtime: cpu 1, msr 3d134080
[    0.777469] MDS CPU bug present and SMT on, data leak possible. See https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/mds.html for more details.
[    0.781409] MMIO Stale Data CPU bug present and SMT on, data leak possible. See https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/processor_mmio_stale_data.html for more details.
[    0.785433] smp: Brought up 1 node, 2 CPUs
[    0.788782] smpboot: Max logical packages: 1
[    0.789408] smpboot: Total of 2 processors activated (9999.99 BogoMIPS)
[    0.795554] node 0 deferred pages initialised in 0ms
[    0.797570] devtmpfs: initialized
[    0.800549] x86/mm: Memory block size: 128MB
[    0.805588] clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 7645041785100000 ns
[    0.813414] futex hash table entries: 512 (order: 3, 32768 bytes, linear)
[    0.817590] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[    0.821176] DMA: preallocated 128 KiB GFP_KERNEL pool for atomic allocations
[    0.825418] DMA: preallocated 128 KiB GFP_KERNEL|GFP_DMA pool for atomic allocations
[    0.829410] DMA: preallocated 128 KiB GFP_KERNEL|GFP_DMA32 pool for atomic allocations
[    0.837419] audit: initializing netlink subsys (disabled)
[    0.841472] thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'fair_share'
[    0.841473] thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'step_wise'
[    0.845642] audit: type=2000 audit(1664284498.244:1): state=initialized audit_enabled=0 res=1
[    0.845578] thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'user_space'
[    0.853460] cpuidle: using governor ladder
[    0.861412] cpuidle: using governor menu
[    0.865516] ACPI: bus type PCI registered
[    0.868850] acpiphp: ACPI Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.5
[    0.873566] PCI: Using configuration type 1 for base access
[    0.882108] Kprobes globally optimized
[    0.885615] HugeTLB registered 1.00 GiB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
[    0.889441] HugeTLB registered 2.00 MiB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
[    1.017504] ACPI: Added _OSI(Module Device)
[    1.021424] ACPI: Added _OSI(Processor Device)
[    1.024946] ACPI: Added _OSI(3.0 _SCP Extensions)
[    1.025409] ACPI: Added _OSI(Processor Aggregator Device)
[    1.029321] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Dell-Video)
[    1.029408] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)
[    1.033310] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-HPI-Hybrid-Graphics)
[    1.034172] ACPI: 3 ACPI AML tables successfully acquired and loaded
[    1.038238] ACPI: Interpreter enabled
[    1.041398] ACPI: (supports S0 S4 S5)
[    1.041408] ACPI: Using IOAPIC for interrupt routing
[    1.045119] PCI: Using host bridge windows from ACPI; if necessary, use "pci=nocrs" and report a bug
[    1.045728] ACPI: Enabled 16 GPEs in block 00 to 0F
[    1.052476] ACPI: PCI Root Bridge [PCI0] (domain 0000 [bus 00-ff])
[    1.053412] acpi PNP0A03:00: _OSC: OS supports [ASPM ClockPM Segments MSI HPX-Type3]
[    1.057415] acpi PNP0A03:00: fail to add MMCONFIG information, can't access extended PCI configuration space under this bridge.
[    1.061714] acpiphp: Slot [3] registered
[    1.065057] acpiphp: Slot [4] registered
[    1.065428] acpiphp: Slot [5] registered
[    1.068743] acpiphp: Slot [6] registered
[    1.069427] acpiphp: Slot [7] registered
[    1.072763] acpiphp: Slot [8] registered
[    1.073430] acpiphp: Slot [9] registered
[    1.076764] acpiphp: Slot [10] registered
[    1.077430] acpiphp: Slot [11] registered
[    1.080856] acpiphp: Slot [12] registered
[    1.081429] acpiphp: Slot [13] registered
[    1.084825] acpiphp: Slot [14] registered
[    1.085428] acpiphp: Slot [15] registered
[    1.088796] acpiphp: Slot [16] registered
[    1.089428] acpiphp: Slot [17] registered
[    1.092761] acpiphp: Slot [18] registered
[    1.093428] acpiphp: Slot [19] registered
[    1.096756] acpiphp: Slot [20] registered
[    1.097428] acpiphp: Slot [21] registered
[    1.100793] acpiphp: Slot [22] registered
[    1.101428] acpiphp: Slot [23] registered
[    1.104754] acpiphp: Slot [24] registered
[    1.105429] acpiphp: Slot [25] registered
[    1.108765] acpiphp: Slot [26] registered
[    1.109427] acpiphp: Slot [27] registered
[    1.112791] acpiphp: Slot [28] registered
[    1.113429] acpiphp: Slot [29] registered
[    1.116748] acpiphp: Slot [30] registered
[    1.117428] acpiphp: Slot [31] registered
[    1.120757] PCI host bridge to bus 0000:00
[    1.121410] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [io  0x0000-0x0cf7 window]
[    1.125408] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [io  0x0d00-0xffff window]
[    1.129408] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x000a0000-0x000bffff window]
[    1.133408] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x80000000-0xfebfffff window]
[    1.137408] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [bus 00-ff]
[    1.141336] pci 0000:00:00.0: [8086:1237] type 00 class 0x060000
[    1.141870] pci 0000:00:01.0: [8086:7000] type 00 class 0x060100
[    1.146516] pci 0000:00:01.3: [8086:7113] type 00 class 0x000000
[    1.150272] pci 0000:00:01.3: quirk: [io  0xb000-0xb03f] claimed by PIIX4 ACPI
[    1.153424] pci 0000:00:01.3: quirk: [io  0xb100-0xb10f] claimed by PIIX4 SMB
[    1.157467] pci 0000:00:01.3: PIIX4 devres E PIO at fff0-ffff
[    1.161421] pci 0000:00:01.3: PIIX4 devres F MMIO at ffc00000-ffffffff
[    1.165423] pci 0000:00:01.3: PIIX4 devres G PIO at fff0-ffff
[    1.169392] pci 0000:00:01.3: PIIX4 devres H MMIO at ffc00000-ffffffff
[    1.169421] pci 0000:00:01.3: PIIX4 devres I PIO at fff0-ffff
[    1.173424] pci 0000:00:01.3: PIIX4 devres J PIO at fff0-ffff
[    1.177411] pci 0000:00:01.3: quirk_piix4_acpi+0x0/0x170 took 27343 usecs
[    1.181764] pci 0000:00:03.0: [1d0f:1111] type 00 class 0x030000
[    1.185953] pci 0000:00:03.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xfe400000-0xfe7fffff pref]
[    1.191003] pci 0000:00:03.0: reg 0x30: [mem 0xfebe0000-0xfebeffff pref]
[    1.193800] pci 0000:00:04.0: [1d0f:8061] type 00 class 0x010802
[    1.198499] pci 0000:00:04.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xfebf0000-0xfebf3fff]
[    1.204156] pci 0000:00:05.0: [1d0f:ec20] type 00 class 0x020000
[    1.205863] pci 0000:00:05.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xfebf4000-0xfebf7fff]
[    1.212400] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKA] (IRQs 5 *10 11)
[    1.213505] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKB] (IRQs 5 *10 11)
[    1.217499] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKC] (IRQs 5 10 *11)
[    1.221502] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKD] (IRQs 5 10 *11)
[    1.225457] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKS] (IRQs *9)
[    1.229583] iommu: Default domain type: Translated 
[    1.233347] pci 0000:00:03.0: vgaarb: setting as boot VGA device
[    1.233404] pci 0000:00:03.0: vgaarb: VGA device added: decodes=io+mem,owns=io+mem,locks=none
[    1.233413] pci 0000:00:03.0: vgaarb: bridge control possible
[    1.237409] vgaarb: loaded
[    1.240400] EDAC MC: Ver: 3.0.0
[    1.241472] NetLabel: Initializing
[    1.245418] NetLabel:  domain hash size = 128
[    1.249407] NetLabel:  protocols = UNLABELED CIPSOv4 CALIPSO
[    1.253423] NetLabel:  unlabeled traffic allowed by default
[    1.257407] PCI: Using ACPI for IRQ routing
[    1.261410] PCI: pci_cache_line_size set to 64 bytes
[    1.261549] e820: reserve RAM buffer [mem 0x0009fc00-0x0009ffff]
[    1.261551] e820: reserve RAM buffer [mem 0x3e3ea000-0x3fffffff]
[    1.261597] hpet0: at MMIO 0xfed00000, IRQs 2, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
[    1.265410] hpet0: 8 comparators, 32-bit 62.500000 MHz counter
[    1.271493] clocksource: Switched to clocksource kvm-clock
[    1.292189] VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.6.0
[    1.295513] VFS: Dquot-cache hash table entries: 512 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
[    1.299975] pnp: PnP ACPI init
[    1.302968] pnp 00:00: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0b00 (active)
[    1.303009] pnp 00:01: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0303 (active)
[    1.303038] pnp 00:02: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0f13 (active)
[    1.303097] pnp 00:03: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0400 (active)
[    1.303153] pnp 00:04: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0501 (active)
[    1.303361] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 5 devices
[    1.313175] clocksource: acpi_pm: mask: 0xffffff max_cycles: 0xffffff, max_idle_ns: 2085701024 ns
[    1.320052] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    1.323607] IP idents hash table entries: 16384 (order: 5, 131072 bytes, linear)
[    1.330159] tcp_listen_portaddr_hash hash table entries: 512 (order: 1, 8192 bytes, linear)
[    1.336822] TCP established hash table entries: 8192 (order: 4, 65536 bytes, linear)
[    1.343219] TCP bind hash table entries: 8192 (order: 5, 131072 bytes, linear)
[    1.349502] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 8192 bind 8192)
[    1.353946] MPTCP token hash table entries: 1024 (order: 2, 24576 bytes, linear)
[    1.360312] UDP hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes, linear)
[    1.364763] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes, linear)
[    1.369364] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    1.372866] NET: Registered protocol family 44
[    1.376381] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 4 [io  0x0000-0x0cf7 window]
[    1.380532] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 5 [io  0x0d00-0xffff window]
[    1.384665] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 6 [mem 0x000a0000-0x000bffff window]
[    1.389072] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 7 [mem 0x80000000-0xfebfffff window]
[    1.393544] pci 0000:00:00.0: Limiting direct PCI/PCI transfers
[    1.397575] pci 0000:00:01.0: Activating ISA DMA hang workarounds
[    1.401817] pci 0000:00:03.0: Video device with shadowed ROM at [mem 0x000c0000-0x000dffff]
[    1.408530] PCI: CLS 0 bytes, default 64
[    1.411866] Trying to unpack rootfs image as initramfs...
[    1.436481] Freeing initrd memory: 10524K
[    1.439944] clocksource: tsc: mask: 0xffffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x240937b9988, max_idle_ns: 440795218083 ns
[    1.447198] clocksource: Switched to clocksource tsc
[    1.547895] check: Scanning for low memory corruption every 60 seconds
[    1.554854] Initialise system trusted keyrings
[    1.558416] Key type blacklist registered
[    1.561800] workingset: timestamp_bits=36 max_order=18 bucket_order=0
[    1.567133] zbud: loaded
[    1.569988] SGI XFS with ACLs, security attributes, quota, no debug enabled
[    1.575060] Key type asymmetric registered
[    1.578443] Asymmetric key parser 'x509' registered
[    1.582145] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 251)
[    1.588490] io scheduler mq-deadline registered
[    1.592061] io scheduler kyber registered
[    1.595427] io scheduler bfq registered
[    1.599093] shpchp: Standard Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.4
[    1.603553] intel_idle: Please enable MWAIT in BIOS SETUP
[    1.603854] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 4 ports, IRQ sharing disabled
[    1.608392] 00:04: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
[    1.615674] nvme nvme0: pci function 0000:00:04.0
[    1.619359] i8042: PNP: PS/2 Controller [PNP0303:KBD,PNP0f13:MOU] at 0x60,0x64 irq 1,12
[    1.619724] PCI Interrupt Link [LNKD] enabled at IRQ 11
[    1.626369] i8042: Warning: Keylock active
[    1.634373] serio: i8042 KBD port at 0x60,0x64 irq 1
[    1.638083] serio: i8042 AUX port at 0x60,0x64 irq 12
[    1.642093] rtc_cmos 00:00: RTC can wake from S4
[    1.649124] rtc_cmos 00:00: registered as rtc0
[    1.649799] nvme nvme0: 2/0/0 default/read/poll queues
[    1.656818] rtc_cmos 00:00: setting system clock to 2022-09-27T13:14:59 UTC (1664284499)
[    1.656820] rtc_cmos 00:00: alarms up to one day, 114 bytes nvram
[    1.656843] intel_pstate: CPU model not supported
[    1.665972]  nvme0n1: p1 p128
[    1.667924] hid: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[    1.678472] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[    1.685564] Segment Routing with IPv6
[    1.688823] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    1.692786] IPI shorthand broadcast: enabled
[    1.696227] sched_clock: Marking stable (988039228, 708169048)->(2004698642, -308490366)
[    1.702831] registered taskstats version 1
[    1.706189] Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates
[    1.711772] Loaded X.509 cert 'Build time autogenerated kernel key: fac365f2d336592a96aa486ff67edc69a1905893'
[    1.719024] zswap: loaded using pool lzo/zbud
[    1.722589] ima: No TPM chip found, activating TPM-bypass!
[    1.726519] ima: Allocated hash algorithm: sha1
[    1.730049] ima: No architecture policies found
[    1.735339] Freeing unused decrypted memory: 2036K
[    1.739539] Freeing unused kernel image (initmem) memory: 2444K
[    1.745426] Write protecting the kernel read-only data: 22528k
[    1.750030] Freeing unused kernel image (text/rodata gap) memory: 2036K
[    1.754693] Freeing unused kernel image (rodata/data gap) memory: 1264K
[    1.759086] Run /init as init process
[    1.762294]   with arguments:
[    1.762295]     /init
[    1.762295]   with environment:
[    1.762296]     HOME=/
[    1.762297]     TERM=linux
[    1.762297]     BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.10.135-122.509.amzn2.x86_64
[    1.762298]     biosdevname=0
[    1.778065] systemd[1]: systemd 219 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA -APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 -SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN)
[    1.790139] systemd[1]: Detected virtualization amazon.
[    1.793925] systemd[1]: Detected architecture x86-64.
[    1.797618] systemd[1]: Running in initial RAM disk.
[    1.803140] systemd[1]: No hostname configured.
[    1.806681] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <localhost>.
[    1.810404] systemd[1]: Initializing machine ID from VM UUID.
[    1.838112] systemd[1]: Reached target Swap.
[    1.842768] systemd[1]: Started Dispatch Password Requests to Console Directory Watch.
[    1.850819] systemd[1]: Reached target Timers.
[    2.021357] XFS (nvme0n1p1): Mounting V5 Filesystem
[    2.158082] input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input0
[    2.167552] XFS (nvme0n1p1): Ending clean mount
[    2.330907] systemd-journald[730]: Received SIGTERM from PID 1 (systemd).
[    2.337914] printk: systemd: 20 output lines suppressed due to ratelimiting
[    2.358856] SELinux:  Runtime disable is deprecated, use selinux=0 on the kernel cmdline.
[    2.365439] SELinux:  Disabled at runtime.
[    2.429460] audit: type=1404 audit(1664284500.276:2): enforcing=0 old_enforcing=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 enabled=0 old-enabled=1 lsm=selinux res=1
[    2.827122] xfs filesystem being remounted at / supports timestamps until 2038 (0x7fffffff)
[    2.868438] ena 0000:00:05.0: Elastic Network Adapter (ENA) v2.7.4g
[    2.882224] ena 0000:00:05.0: ENA device version: 0.10
[    2.886546] ena 0000:00:05.0: ENA controller version: 0.0.1 implementation version 1
[    2.896619] systemd-journald[1190]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1
[    2.953435] ena 0000:00:05.0: LLQ is not supported Fallback to host mode policy.
[    2.972054] ena 0000:00:05.0: Elastic Network Adapter (ENA) found at mem febf4000, mac addr 0e:08:bc:ee:a3:a6
[    3.499349] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input3
[    3.562336] ACPI: Power Button [PWRF]
[    3.581368] input: Sleep Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSLPBN:00/input/input4
[    3.609853] ACPI: Sleep Button [SLPF]
[    3.729446] input: ImPS/2 Generic Wheel Mouse as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input5
[    3.787051] cryptd: max_cpu_qlen set to 1000
[    3.849634] AVX2 version of gcm_enc/dec engaged.
[    3.853675] AES CTR mode by8 optimization enabled
[    3.853750] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    4.241130] device-mapper: uevent: version 1.0.3
[    4.245459] device-mapper: ioctl: 4.43.0-ioctl (2020-10-01) initialised: dm-devel@redhat.com
[    4.365543] RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
[    4.365544] RPC: Registered udp transport module.
[    4.365544] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
[    4.365545] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
[    4.459333] xfs filesystem being remounted at /tmp supports timestamps until 2038 (0x7fffffff)
[    4.459814] xfs filesystem being remounted at /var/tmp supports timestamps until 2038 (0x7fffffff)
[    5.655228] ena 0000:00:05.0 eth0: Local page cache is disabled for less than 16 channels
[    6.687093] xfs filesystem being remounted at /tmp supports timestamps until 2038 (0x7fffffff)
[    6.687576] xfs filesystem being remounted at /var/tmp supports timestamps until 2038 (0x7fffffff)
[  383.753381] systemd-sysv-generator[3046]: Configuration file /usr/lib/systemd/system/codedeploy-agent.service is marked executable. Please remove executable permission bits. Proceeding anyway.
[  383.829685] systemd-sysv-generator[3066]: Configuration file /usr/lib/systemd/system/codedeploy-agent.service is marked executable. Please remove executable permission bits. Proceeding anyway.
[  408.424891] systemd-sysv-generator[3206]: Configuration file /usr/lib/systemd/system/codedeploy-agent.service is marked executable. Please remove executable permission bits. Proceeding anyway.
[  408.487008] systemd-sysv-generator[3225]: Configuration file /usr/lib/systemd/system/codedeploy-agent.service is marked executable. Please remove executable permission bits. Proceeding anyway.
[  892.144130] systemd-sysv-generator[7167]: Configuration file /usr/lib/systemd/system/codedeploy-agent.service is marked executable. Please remove executable permission bits. Proceeding anyway.
[  892.226105] systemd-sysv-generator[7187]: Configuration file /usr/lib/systemd/system/codedeploy-agent.service is marked executable. Please remove executable permission bits. Proceeding anyway.
```

`var/log/messages` output

```
Sep 27 14:59:03 ip-172-31-3-156 dhclient[2086]: XMT: Solicit on eth0, interval 130770ms.
Sep 27 15:00:01 ip-172-31-3-156 systemd: Started Session 13 of user root.
Sep 27 15:01:01 ip-172-31-3-156 systemd: Removed slice User Slice of root.
Sep 27 15:01:01 ip-172-31-3-156 systemd: Created slice User Slice of root.
Sep 27 15:01:01 ip-172-31-3-156 systemd: Started Session 14 of user root.
Sep 27 15:01:01 ip-172-31-3-156 systemd: Removed slice User Slice of root.
Sep 27 15:01:14 ip-172-31-3-156 dhclient[2086]: XMT: Solicit on eth0, interval 114790ms.
Sep 27 15:03:09 ip-172-31-3-156 dhclient[2086]: XMT: Solicit on eth0, interval 130520ms.
Sep 27 15:05:19 ip-172-31-3-156 dhclient[2086]: XMT: Solicit on eth0, interval 114090ms.
Sep 27 15:07:13 ip-172-31-3-156 dhclient[2086]: XMT: Solicit on eth0, interval 127250ms.
Sep 27 15:09:21 ip-172-31-3-156 dhclient[2086]: XMT: Solicit on eth0, interval 116810ms.
Sep 27 15:10:01 ip-172-31-3-156 systemd: Created slice User Slice of root.
Sep 27 15:10:01 ip-172-31-3-156 systemd: Started Session 15 of user root.
Sep 27 15:10:01 ip-172-31-3-156 systemd: Removed slice User Slice of root.
Sep 27 15:11:18 ip-172-31-3-156 dhclient[2086]: XMT: Solicit on eth0, interval 125810ms.
Sep 27 15:13:24 ip-172-31-3-156 dhclient[2086]: XMT: Solicit on eth0, interval 109230ms.
Sep 27 15:15:13 ip-172-31-3-156 dhclient[2086]: XMT: Solicit on eth0, interval 115140ms.
Sep 27 15:17:08 ip-172-31-3-156 dhclient[2086]: XMT: Solicit on eth0, interval 113270ms.
Sep 27 15:19:01 ip-172-31-3-156 dhclient[2086]: XMT: Solicit on eth0, interval 110410ms.
Sep 27 15:20:01 ip-172-31-3-156 systemd: Created slice User Slice of root.
Sep 27 15:20:01 ip-172-31-3-156 systemd: Started Session 16 of user root.
Sep 27 15:20:01 ip-172-31-3-156 systemd: Removed slice User Slice of root.
Sep 27 15:20:52 ip-172-31-3-156 dhclient[2086]: XMT: Solicit on eth0, interval 120500ms.
Sep 27 15:22:53 ip-172-31-3-156 dhclient[2086]: XMT: Solicit on eth0, interval 124260ms.
Sep 27 15:22:57 ip-172-31-3-156 systemd: Started Session 17 of user ec2-user.
Sep 27 15:22:57 ip-172-31-3-156 systemd-logind: New session 17 of user ec2-user.
Sep 27 15:24:57 ip-172-31-3-156 dhclient[2086]: XMT: Solicit on eth0, interval 109210ms.
Sep 27 15:26:18 ip-172-31-3-156 dhclient[2039]: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 172.31.0.1 port 67 (xid=0x2ac6e237)
Sep 27 15:26:18 ip-172-31-3-156 dhclient[2039]: DHCPACK from 172.31.0.1 (xid=0x2ac6e237)
Sep 27 15:26:19 ip-172-31-3-156 NET: dhclient: Locked /run/dhclient/resolv.lock
Sep 27 15:26:19 ip-172-31-3-156 dhclient[2039]: bound to 172.31.3.156 -- renewal in 1779 seconds.
Sep 27 15:26:19 ip-172-31-3-156 ec2net: [get_meta] Querying IMDS for meta-data/network/interfaces/macs/0e:08:bc:ee:a3:a6/local-ipv4s
Sep 27 15:26:19 ip-172-31-3-156 ec2net: [get_meta] Getting token for IMDSv2.
Sep 27 15:26:19 ip-172-31-3-156 ec2net: [get_meta] Trying to get http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/network/interfaces/macs/0e:08:bc:ee:a3:a6/local-ipv4s
Sep 27 15:26:19 ip-172-31-3-156 ec2net: [remove_aliases] Removing aliases of eth0
Sep 27 15:26:46 ip-172-31-3-156 dhclient[2086]: XMT: Solicit on eth0, interval 122080ms.
Sep 27 15:27:05 ip-172-31-3-156 systemd: log4j-cve-2021-44228-hotpatch.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Sep 27 15:27:05 ip-172-31-3-156 systemd: Stopped Run the CVE-2021-44228 hotfix script.
Sep 27 15:27:05 ip-172-31-3-156 systemd: Started Run the CVE-2021-44228 hotfix script.
Sep 27 15:27:05 ip-172-31-3-156 log4j-cve-2021-44228-hotpatch: [log4j-hotpatch] Starting up now...
Sep 27 15:27:05 ip-172-31-3-156 root: Starting up now...
Sep 27 15:27:05 ip-172-31-3-156 log4j-cve-2021-44228-hotpatch: [log4j-hotpatch] Found JVMs with pids [4857]
Sep 27 15:27:05 ip-172-31-3-156 root: Found JVMs with pids [4857]
Sep 27 15:27:05 ip-172-31-3-156 log4j-cve-2021-44228-hotpatch: [log4j-hotpatch] Attempting to patch 4857
Sep 27 15:27:05 ip-172-31-3-156 root: Attempting to patch 4857
Sep 27 15:27:07 ip-172-31-3-156 log4j-cve-2021-44228-hotpatch: [log4j-hotpatch] Found JVM running with effective UID of 0
Sep 27 15:27:07 ip-172-31-3-156 root: Found JVM running with effective UID of 0
Sep 27 15:27:07 ip-172-31-3-156 log4j-cve-2021-44228-hotpatch: [log4j-hotpatch] Found JVM for pid 4857 at /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-amazon-corretto.x86_64/bin/java
Sep 27 15:27:07 ip-172-31-3-156 root: Found JVM for pid 4857 at /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-amazon-corretto.x86_64/bin/java
Sep 27 15:27:07 ip-172-31-3-156 systemd: Created slice User Slice of root.
Sep 27 15:27:07 ip-172-31-3-156 systemd: Started Session c22 of user root.
Sep 27 15:27:07 ip-172-31-3-156 systemd: Removed slice User Slice of root.
Sep 27 15:27:07 ip-172-31-3-156 log4j-cve-2021-44228-hotpatch: [log4j-hotpatch] JVM version is openjdk version "17.0.4.1" 2022-08-12 LTS
Sep 27 15:27:07 ip-172-31-3-156 root: JVM version is openjdk version "17.0.4.1" 2022-08-12 LTS
Sep 27 15:27:07 ip-172-31-3-156 log4j-cve-2021-44228-hotpatch: [log4j-hotpatch] Identified JVM[openjdk] of (openjdk version "17.0.4.1" 2022-08-12 LTS) with major version 17
Sep 27 15:27:07 ip-172-31-3-156 root: Identified JVM[openjdk] of (openjdk version "17.0.4.1" 2022-08-12 LTS) with major version 17
Sep 27 15:27:08 ip-172-31-3-156 systemd: Created slice User Slice of root.
Sep 27 15:27:08 ip-172-31-3-156 systemd: Started Session c23 of user root.
Sep 27 15:27:08 ip-172-31-3-156 log4j-cve-2021-44228-hotpatch: [log4j-hotpatch] Using Java 17 hotpatch
Sep 27 15:27:08 ip-172-31-3-156 systemd: Removed slice User Slice of root.
Sep 27 15:27:08 ip-172-31-3-156 root: Using Java 17 hotpatch
Sep 27 15:27:08 ip-172-31-3-156 systemd: Created slice User Slice of root.
Sep 27 15:27:08 ip-172-31-3-156 systemd: Started Session c24 of user root.
Sep 27 15:27:08 ip-172-31-3-156 systemd: Removed slice User Slice of root.
Sep 27 15:27:08 ip-172-31-3-156 log4j-cve-2021-44228-hotpatch: [log4j-hotpatch] Hotpatch application returned 0
Sep 27 15:27:08 ip-172-31-3-156 root: Hotpatch application returned 0
Sep 27 15:28:48 ip-172-31-3-156 dhclient[2086]: XMT: Solicit on eth0, interval 121490ms.
Sep 27 15:30:01 ip-172-31-3-156 systemd: Created slice User Slice of root.
Sep 27 15:30:01 ip-172-31-3-156 systemd: Started Session 18 of user root.
Sep 27 15:30:01 ip-172-31-3-156 systemd: Removed slice User Slice of root.
Sep 27 15:30:50 ip-172-31-3-156 dhclient[2086]: XMT: Solicit on eth0, interval 115800ms.
Sep 27 15:32:46 ip-172-31-3-156 dhclient[2086]: XMT: Solicit on eth0, interval 125350ms.
Sep 27 15:34:51 ip-172-31-3-156 dhclient[2086]: XMT: Solicit on eth0, interval 117180ms.
Sep 27 15:36:49 ip-172-31-3-156 dhclient[2086]: XMT: Solicit on eth0, interval 129010ms.
Sep 27 15:38:58 ip-172-31-3-156 dhclient[2086]: XMT: Solicit on eth0, interval 129190ms.
Sep 27 15:40:01 ip-172-31-3-156 systemd: Created slice User Slice of root.
Sep 27 15:40:01 ip-172-31-3-156 systemd: Started Session 19 of user root.
Sep 27 15:40:01 ip-172-31-3-156 systemd: Removed slice User Slice of root.
Sep 27 15:41:07 ip-172-31-3-156 dhclient[2086]: XMT: Solicit on eth0, interval 128040ms.
Sep 27 15:43:15 ip-172-31-3-156 dhclient[2086]: XMT: Solicit on eth0, interval 129220ms.
Sep 27 15:45:24 ip-172-31-3-156 dhclient[2086]: XMT: Solicit on eth0, interval 126940ms.
```

Comment: Stopped working means what? Killed? What was the last log entry? Is there an entry in CloudTrail for TerminateInstances?

Comment: @peterulb Stopped means that the application just stopped processing. And it does not schedule to start the frow again. So the EC2 instance is alive, but the job inside was stopped.

Comment: So what about CloudTrail entries? Did you SSH into the instance to have a look at the logs mentioned here: https://serverfault.com/a/269559

Comment: Didn't enable CloudTrail yet and didn't at the `logfiles /var/log/kern.log, /var/log/messages, or /var/log/syslog`.

Comment: for Java applications you can enable remote debugging by adding some java options, then opening the required ports to you and attaching a debugger or profiler. https://kent-broadbent.medium.com/debugging-a-java-application-running-in-ec2-51ee3e0bca11 has some info on that

Comment: @peterulb added `/var/log/messages` and `dmesg` output. Other log files do not exist. But didn't find anything that could help.

Comment: is the output of `log.error` etc visible anywhere? If not, you can configure the logger to write a log file locally on the instance and look in there for errors as well. And since you seem to use code deploy, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/deployments-view-logs.html might have logs regarding the application launch itself

Comment: @zapl Reconfigured application to writer error logs to separate file but this file is empty((

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the reason. The problem was in the code. One of the threads was stuck in the infinite loop because I write the wrong condition.
Nevertheless, what helps me to sort it out was `jstack` tool.
I ran `ps -C java -o pid` command to find the PID of the java application than `jstack PID` and get very understandable logs of where and what thread stuck.